# How can I setup Eclipse so it would place additional space after code block?

Tags: java, eclipse, sonarqube

I receive a sonar warning because it is not pleased with this syntax:

```
new Thread() {

                /**
                 * {@inheritDoc}
                 */
                @Override
                public void run() {
                }

            }.start();
```

More specifically, it asks for a white space after any '}' (and there is none before `.start()`). How can I set this in eclipse ?

Comment: add (new Thread() {..}).start?

Answer (score 3):

Goto **Window → Preferences**:

[image]

Choose **Formatter → Edit**:

[image]

Choose **White Space**:

Then you'll have many settings that you can reconfigure: Set space before/after functions etc..

Comment: Yes I have seen this formatter editor, but I didn't see any options that matched my issue.